# How much energy does a PV cell need to work?

Tags: energy, photons, laser, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

How much energy does a $1m^2$ photovolatic/solar cell need to work? Can it work using a bunch of Laser lights?
Edit: Ok so this PV cell is $1m^2$ is dimesions. The N-type has silicon doped with phosphorous and the P-type is silicon doped with boron.
Thanks.

Comment: How one can answer this question without knowledge about the value of the potential barrier (depends on the solar cells material combinations  and the range of wavelengths (visible light, infrared, ultraviolet) for which the cell is designed.

Comment: For a single band gap cell, you need at least one photon with an energy level greater than the band gap is required to drive an electron.  Losses mean that not every photon will contribute to electrical production, though.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I have now edited the question with more details

Comment: @BowlOfRed And can a PV cell work with the help of lasers? And am i right that a photon has more energy than the required amout of energy to lose a electron that excess energy goes waste and if that photon has twice the energy needed then that energy is used by 2 electrons right?

Comment: Yes, the excess energy will probably go to waste.  No, most cells will not be able to take a double-energy photon and raise 2 electrons.  Lasers can certainly drive PV, but it would be unusual to do so.